# Jooq Liquibase dependencies between modules and tables

Tags: maven, liquibase, jooq

I have a multi-maven module project and I have two modules that contain some Liquibase configuration with tables.
I want to add a foreign key between two tables but table A is in module A and table B is in module B. Problem is that during compilation I got an error because Liquibase doesn't see table A...

Is some solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this problem only appears when you use jOOQ's [`LiquibaseDatabase`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-liquibase/), which simulates your liquibase migrations for code generation. I can think of a few solutions to this problem:

- Use a [test containers based code generation instead](https://blog.jooq.org/using-testcontainers-to-generate-jooq-code/). The blog post before uses Flyway, but it will work the same with Liquibase. This means that during your build of both modules, you'll have a running database instance, which will be up to date by the time you generate jOOQ code. That also removes any simulation related issues, such as allowing you to use vendor specific features of your RDBMS.
- Extract the database change management and schema into another module, making the schema "global", instead of module dependent. Your foreign key kinda hints at the schema being global anyway. The relational model isn't really directed in a tree form. It's a graph. Sooner rather than later, you'll have a key from A to B and your dependencies will become cyclic.
- Stay purely "modular" and make the schemas independent, removing the key. Of course, data integrity is a good thing, so the price to pay for this is high, but it would solve your immediate problem.
- Remove the key from jOOQ's code generation and declare a [synthetic foreign key in jOOQ's code generation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-synthetic-objects/codegen-database-synthetic-fks/) (though, B would still somehow have to know about A in the generation process)
- Run both liquibase migrations for A *and* B when you generate code for module B. That way, B has all the information available again.

Which to pick is a subjective choice and doesn't have a clear answer. But at least, this gives you options.